# Tf to tf2 upgrade adaptation problem

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I wanna update tf to tf2 in my code, but get some question about it.

There are `tf` part :

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
try
{
    listener.waitForTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(2));
    listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), transform);
}
catch(tf::TransformException ex)
{
    ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
    ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", QString::fromStdString(ex.what()));
    return ;
}
geometry_msgs::Transform tt;
tf::transformTFToMsg(transform, tt);
pose.position.x = tt.translation.x;
pose.position.y = tt.translation.y;
pose.position.z = tt.translation.z;
pose.orientation.x = tt.rotation.x;
pose.orientation.y = tt.rotation.y;
pose.orientation.z = tt.rotation.z;
pose.orientation.w = tt.rotation.w;
```

`pose` is a parameter, via `geometry_msgs::Pose &pose`

When I follow the doc to update to tf2, I get some wrong.

There are tf2 part:

```
tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

try
{
    transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0));
}
catch (tf2::TransformException &ex){
    ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
    ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
}
geometry_msgs::Transform tt;
tf::transformTFToMsg(transformStamped, tt);
```

I Don't know how to transfrom data under tf2, and I didn‘t find the relevant function in doc.

I want to know how to modify my code to achieve the same result?

Is there a function just like `transformTFToMsg` I can replace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295323/tf-to-tf2-upgrade-adaptation-problem/) by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your first example, you make a `tf::StampedTransform` to hold the transform, then use `transformTFToMsg` to put it into a message object.

In the second example, `tf2` is *already* returning a `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` message type (instead of a `StampedTransform` object). So you're trying to convert a message to a message. You're effectively doing this:

```
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
geometry_msgs::Transform tt;
tf::transformTFToMsg(transformStamped, tt);
```

But those are both message types, so you don't need to do that at all. You have two options:

1. Use `transformStamped` instead of `tt` in the rest of your code, since they are both messages.
2. Just do this:

   ```
   geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
   <your transform try/catch block>
   geometry_msgs::Transform tt = transformStamped.transform;
   ```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-06-26**:
Thank you for your detailed explanation, it really wake me up.